# Annoying accent popup after upgrade from Debian 9 to 10

Tags: debian, keyboard

My Debian 9 was configured to have no dead keys in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

After the update to Debian 10 this stops working. When ever I type "^" in `xterm` I get an annoying popup:

> [image: screenshot]

And when I type a "`" in Firefox it gets underlined.

Which program does this and how to stop it?

**Update:**

```
$ ibus read-config
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general
  dconf-preserve-name-prefixes: ['/desktop/ibus/engine/pinyin', '/desktop/ibus/engine/bopomofo', '/desktop/ibus/engine/hangul']
  use-system-keyboard-layout: false
  embed-preedit-text: true
  enable-by-default: false
  use-global-engine: true
  use-xmodmap: true
  switcher-delay-time: 400
  version: '1.5.19'
  engines-order: @as []
  preload-engines: ['xkb:de::ger']
  xkb-latin-layouts: ['ara', 'bg', 'cz', 'dev', 'gr', 'gur', 'in', 'jp(kana)', 'mal', 'mkd', 'ru', 'ua']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey
  next-engine: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  disable-unconditional: @as []
  enable-unconditional: @as []
  trigger: ['Control+space', 'Zenkaku_Hankaku', 'Alt+Kanji', 'Alt+grave', 'Hangul', 'Alt+Release+Alt_R']
  previous-engine: @as []
  prev-engine: @as []
  next-engine-in-menu: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  triggers: ['space']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.panel
  x: -1
  property-icon-delay-time: 500
  y: -1
  show: 0
  lookup-table-orientation: 1
  xkb-icon-rgba: '#415099'
  auto-hide-timeout: 10000
  show-im-name: false
  follow-input-cursor-when-always-shown: false
  custom-font: 'Sans 10'
  show-icon-on-systray: true
  use-custom-font: false
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji
  load-emoji-at-startup: true
  favorite-annotations: @as []
  favorites: @as []
  hotkey: ['e']
  has-partial-match: false
  unicode-hotkey: ['u']
  partial-match-length: 3
  load-unicode-at-startup: false
  partial-match-condition: 0
  font: 'Monospace 16'
  lang: 'en'
```

Comment: What desktop environment? Can you find out what input method you're using (e.g. ibus)?

Comment: @Mikel No desktop environment. Just Fluxbox with Xterm. I run X11 with `startx`, which runs `xinit`, which starts `Xorg` and `fluxbox`. Pretty old school. BTW what is `ibus`?

Comment: You should be able to see which input method you're using by running `im-config`.

Comment: @Mikel Thanks! `run_im xim` in `~/.xinputrc` solved it.